# What do we call quality management system software?

Tags: single-word-requests, software

Is there a specific name for all kind of software related to quality management system, i.e. ISO 9001.

being more specific, when in business someone talks about an ERP, everybody knows what does that mean, or a CRM.

Comment: Are thinking about a bug-tracker or defect management software?

Comment: @Jim I think he is thinking of [Quality management system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_management_system) software.

Comment: @augurar But he uses the words "Quality management System" in his title, so I doubt he's looking for those words.

Comment: @Jim My point is "quality management system" is a specific piece of business jargon that does not need to be clarified.

Comment: This question is not about the English language, may be asked on an appropriate tech/management Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

This type of software is called "quality management software".